# How do I get Page X or Y into a confluence pdf export?

Tags: confluence

Im trying to get the Page X of Y into the footer of the pdf that is exported from confluence. I can see from the instructions in from atlissian https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/customize-exports-to-pdf-190480945.html#CustomizeExportstoPDF-HeadersandFooters how to add "Page X" but not page x of y
x = page number
y = total number of pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get the total number of the page with following since Confluence takes the total number from `counter(pages)` :

```
content: "page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
```